# Search function with time complexity O(lg n)

Tags: time, time-complexity

I needed to create a search function with time complexity O(lgn) that would return the position that a certain value x would go in a tuple.

For example, `search(8, (2, 7, 12))` would return 2,
`search(-5, (2, 3, 4, 10))` would return 0 and
`search(6, (4, 6, 12))` would return 1.
with the tuple already sorted
I wrote the following code:

```
    def search(x,seq):
        for i in seq:
            if x<i:
                return seq.index(i)
            elif x == i:
                return seq.index(i)
            elif x>seq[-1]:
                return (seq.index(seq[-1]))+1
```

Does this code have time complexity O(lgn)?

Comment: Is a tuple always in a sorted order, as one could assume from your examples?

Comment: yup, it is! sorry forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is `O(n)`.

Since you mentioned a tuple will always be in a sorted order, you can apply [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which runs in `O(lg(n))`, to find the appropriate index.